# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - how to get all the tag value data

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

ERROR： **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Could you please tell me how to get all the tag value data

```js
const Influencers = (props: any) => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState({});
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("/api/influencers/" + props.match.params.influencer)
            .then(async (res) => {
                setSelectedOptions(res.data.tags.value);
            });
    }, []);
};
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't this line   setSelectedOptions(res.data.tags.value) just be   setSelectedOptions(res.data.tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Influencers = (props: any) => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState({});
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("/api/influencers/" + props.match.params.influencer)
            .then(async (res) => {
                setSelectedOptions(res.data.tags.map(tag => tag.value));
            });
    }, []);
};
```